# Upload multiple csv file to multiple tables sqlServer

Tags: sql-server, restore, table, csv

I have over than 200 csv files that each of them is diffrent table.

I create now a new DB and want to upload them all so I will have all the table.

I not accessable to old DB to backup in diffrent way.

I looking for a simple way to do it fast  (script/gui/ 3pary tool)

I found I can do it with sqlServer gui but I cant upload there multiple files, only 1 by 1, so it will takes hours.

I saw this post [How to upload multiple csv files to sql server without constrains](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/212452/how-to-upload-multiple-csv-files-to-sql-server-without-constrains) but it not help me, not found there any solution.

Comment: You could use a PowerShell script to create the tables and import data but the code would need to determine table names based on file names, determine column names based on the file header names (if you have those), and guess at proper column data types. If you don't have the source database schema available, the best you can do is guess at data types.

Comment: All is on csv files, but how can I put them all in DB with power shell

Answer (score 1):

I you want to use powershell to upload these CSV files, without having to code/script, take a look [dbatools.io](https://dbatools.io). Look for the cmdlet [Import-DbaCsv](https://dbatools.io/functions/import-dbacsv)

All the documentation is available on the site. Just download the tools from github or the powershell gallery.

You can use [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) cmdlet to get all the CSV files in a folder and use the pipeline to send the files to `Import-DbaCsv` (optionally specifying the `-AutoCreateTable` flag). For example:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Path\To\your\CSVs" | ForEach-Object {
    Import-DbaCsv -Csv $_.FullName -SQLInstance "localhost" -Database "yourdb" -AutoCreateTable
}
```

[image: i ❤️ pwsh]

Comment: I didn't understand how to install this module offline , I follow https://dbatools.io/offline/  I use in win 7 so I download https://powershellgallery.com/api/v2/package/dbatools and change the extention to zip , and extract it to the powelshell module ,  now what? how to I install it?

Comment: did you follow the instructions at https://dbatools.io/download/

Comment: yes but I think I miss something , can you please help me with that ?

Comment: offline instructions. Unzip file and save to c:\programfiles\WindowsPowerShell\Modules. Just name the folder dbatools. Open a powershell prompt and run the command Get-ChildItem -Recurse c:\programfiles\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\dbatools | Unblock-File . Update the $env:PSMODULEPATH per this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/developer/module/modifying-the-psmodulepath-installation-path

Comment: That what I did ,save it to `\Module `, Don't I need to run something to install it?  when I run on sqlserverPowerShell `Import-dbacsvtosql` I got error

Comment: if you follow the instructions I provided you can call the dbatools from any location

Comment: why you can't simple tell me what I did wrong? why you continue tell again and again about the  instructions  , I follow them , maybe I miss something so that why I asking help. you can simply help and tell me

Comment: Can you provide the error that you got when you ran the command? The error will help me tell you when went wrong. My guess its the $env:PSModulePath is not updated to the location that you saved dbatools. "C:\ProgramFiles\WindowsPowershell\Modules" is aleady part the $env:PSMODULEPATH.

Comment: when I type `$env:PSMODULEPATH` 
 in sqlserver powershell I see `C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules`   so I need to put https://powershellgallery.com/api/v2/package/dbatools extract and rename to dbatools in and put it on `C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules`  direcroty, and that need to work without any instalation?